# I want to open a location from the web in google earth (with a link?)

Tags: kml, google-earth, kmz

I have a hosted database I work with that allows me to drop in links with some formula capability.  I can string together an address and generate a Google Maps query that works, but if I want to open that query in Google Earth on a user's computer, how can I do that?

Comment: Are you talking about GE plugin for browsers or GE software? In first case it's really not much different than Google Maps - just use GE tutorials/demos from google. In second scenario you would need a link to generate a kml file and point to that created kml file. If they have GE installed and it's set to be default client for kml it should automatically open it.  http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kml_tut.html

Comment: Batch Geo ended up solving my problem.  I ended up just utilizing Google Maps as my option since all users would be able to access that.  There was, however, a limit to the number of places I could plot in my generated KML file, but Batch Geo's limit was considerably higher.  It provided a solution, albeit slightly less tailored to my needs.  Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch Geo ended up solving my problem. I ended up just utilizing Google Maps as my option since all users would be able to access that. There was, however, a limit to the number of places I could plot in my generated KML file, but Batch Geo's limit was considerably higher. It provided a solution, albeit slightly less tailored to my needs.